# CSS animation relative to current screen position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to implement some CSS Keyframe animations on my application, which get triggered on different events. 

The animation consists of a unicorn flying up from the bottom of the screen, stopping in the middle for a second, and then moving up out of the screen. 
 The problem comes when different users have different amounts on content on the page, making the page height bigger.

#### I want the animation to stop for a second relative to users position, in the middle of the users view, not relative to the page height.

This is my code so far:

```
 <img src="../***" v-if="aCounter === 1" class="unicornUp" alt="Unicorn"> 

.unicornUp {
  position:absolute;

  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  right:20%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:99;
  animation-name: unicornMoveUp;
  animation-duration: 3s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes unicornMoveUp {
  from { bottom: 0; opacity: 1;}
  20% {bottom:20%;opacity: 1;transform: rotate(5deg);}
  40% {bottom: 50%;opacity: 1;}
  60% {bottom: 50%;opacity: 1; transform: rotate(-5deg);}
  80% {bottom: 60%; opacity: 1;}
  100% {bottom: 90%; opacity: 0;}
}
```

I've been thinking about a sticky parent div, but I'm not sure if this is even correct and where to start.
 Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try to use 'vh' and 'vw' css units instead of '%'

Comment: Thats the last thing i tried, did not manage to get any better results. I would somehow need to get the animated svg to start at the scroll position I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `position: fixed` instead, as as opposed to `position: absolute` which is relative to the entire document, `fixed` is relative to the viewport i.e. the screen

Comment: I'm glad I could help!! We're all a bunch of noobs, and the more we realize it the better we are at learning, it's the Dunning-Kruger Effect!